# Credentials in request header for REST query

Tags: c#, vb.net, rest, google-chrome-app

I try to get a `token` from our dataproviders `rest api`. I tried the following code as well as `Chrome Rest Console` and always get `401` Username or Password is not correct. I double checked this and got it from the provider as well, my `username:pass` combinatin is right.

Maybe the problem is here. The API description says: `/authenticate(POST) username and password need to be send in the request header`In Chrome as well as in `.net` I use the `basic auth`, is it possible that the problem is there? Or does anyone has an idea, since I am running out of ideas.

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim client = New RestClient("https://test.com/web/api")
    client.Authenticator = New Authenticators.HttpBasicAuthenticator("user.name", "password")
    Dim request = New RestRequest("/authenticate", Method.POST)
    Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
    response = client.Execute(request)
    Dim authroizationHeaderFromResponse = response.Headers.FirstOrDefault(Function(h) h.Name = "Authorization")
    Console.WriteLine(authroizationHeaderFromResponse.ToString)
    If authroizationHeaderFromResponse IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(authroizationHeaderFromResponse.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: See if there's a request.Headers.Add(name, value) feature or somesuch...should be a name-value pair.

Comment: I tried that already, same problem.